Unable to sync the spark-operator chart 2.0.0-rc.0 using ArgoCD
I have created an argoCD app which install the spark-operator using the according chart but 4 object can't be synced:
argocd app wait spark-operator| grep Out
2024-08-30T10:14:18+02:00   apps                         Deployment                      spark-operator  spark-operator-controller               OutOfSync  Healthy              deployment.apps/spark-operator-controller serverside-applied
2024-08-30T10:14:18+02:00  admissionregistration.k8s.io  ValidatingWebhookConfiguration                  spark-operator-webhook                  OutOfSync                       
2024-08-30T10:14:18+02:00   apps                      Deployment                spark-operator  spark-operator-webhook                           OutOfSync  Healthy              deployment.apps/spark-operator-webhook serverside-applied
2024-08-30T10:14:18+02:00  admissionregistration.k8s.io  MutatingWebhookConfiguration                  spark-operator-webhook                           OutOfSync     

Here is my spark-operator application specification:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: spark-operator
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: spark-operator
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: fink
    app.kubernetes.io/component: operator
  finalizers:
  - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    chart: spark-operator
    repoURL: https://kubeflow.github.io/spark-operator
    targetRevision: 2.0.0-rc.0
    helm:
      releaseName: spark-operator
      valuesObject:
        webhook:
          enable: true
        spark:
          jobNamespaces: ["{{.Values.spec.sparkNamespace}}"]
  destination:
    server: {{ .Values.spec.destination.server }}
    namespace: spark-operator
  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
      # See https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/820 and https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/13100
      - ServerSideApply=true
      - ApplyOutOfSyncOnly=true

Thanks in advance!

Upgrading argoCD operator from "v0.10.0" to "v0.11.0", and argocd from "v2.11.2" to "v2.12.3" fixed this issue.
